# Pytorch & Pyinstaller (4GB dist folder )

Tags: qt, pytorch, pyinstaller

I was able to pack a small example app that includes pytorch and pyQt using Pyinstaller but the dist folder is 4GB .

All I am doing is printing pytorch version on QLabel !

```
 from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, 
 QPushButton, QWidget
 from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
 import sys, os
 from torch import __version__
```

Am I using Pyinstaller the wrong way ?